# Get a list Id using javascript?

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, jquery, newform

I'm trying to trigger the `NewForm.aspx` of a list by clicking on a link.
I would like to known how to get a list ID using JavaScript (Or jQuery)? (SP2010)
I've already tried :

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
```

web contains an empty object so I cannot use it. why ?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 or 2010?

Comment: Is ``SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()`` available in 2010?

Comment: for **SharePoint Foundation 2010** only. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407815(v=office.14).aspx @DannyEngelman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be some thing like following

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Name of the List');
context.load(list, 'Id');
```

In the success, try

```
var listId = list.get_id();
```

**Update** for `web` is `undefined`

Run code under `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()`

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListId, "sp.js");
var list;

function getListId() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Name of the List');
    context.load(list, 'Id');

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, success), Function.createDelegate(this, error));

}


function success() {
    listId = list.get_id();
    console.log(listId);
}

function error(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: run your code under `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`

Comment: see my update .... @ameliapond

Comment: opps.. run my updated code

Comment: Any help from updated code? @ameliapond

Comment: My mistake. See update

Comment: Is it worked? then mark the answer@ameliapond

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32215/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-ameliapond).

Comment: As of SP2010, you can find the list id in `_spPageContextInfo.pageListId`. For a great example of its usage, you may want to have a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/101015/63990.

Comment: @Vitali Climenco , I think your comment should be listed as an answer so it's more visible. This is by far the best solution since SharePoint has already made it available as a variable. I almost missed this because I had to expand the comments to see it!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this myself.

In some cases, you should be able to use the SP object for this.

Thought it may come in handy in case someone else bumps into this post.

```
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()
```

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422939/get-currently-selected-list-in-javascript-on-load-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

As per @VitaliClimenco's comment, the list id is stored in the global javascript object [_spPageContextInfo](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29766.sharepoint-understanding-the-sppagecontextinfo-object.aspx) : `_spPageContextInfo.pageListId`.