# Get the list ID passed back

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

The following code is working to show the List GUID in the console but I cannot figure out how to get it to pass the value back for use in another function.

Shouldn't there be a `return;` command in the code below so that it simply passes back the list ID? I don't understand how to use the success section.

How do I get the GUID passed back in SharePoint 2010?

```
var list;

function getListId(myListName) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(myListName);
    context.load(list, 'Id');

    context.executeQueryAsync(
       Function.createDelegate(this, success), 
       Function.createDelegate(this, error));
}

function success() {
    listId = list.get_id();
    console.log(listId);
}

function error(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Check this similar question. you can find answer too [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163504/get-a-list-id-using-javascript](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163504/get-a-list-id-using-javascript)

Comment: @SureshBolineni that is where I started but I could not get it to work our for what I am looking for.

Comment: For those suggesting to place my function call in the success, I don't understand. I am use to a function passing back its value. I don't like using a public/global variable to get data because they are corruptible. I guess I am missing some JavaScript fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give `sp.js` and `sp.runtime.js` reference.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>`

you can view this similar 
[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163504/get-a-l‌​ist-id-using-javascr‌​ipt](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163504/get-a-l%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bist-id-using-javascr%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bipt)

Answer (score 2):

### Passing data to other JavaScript Functions

To pass data you have to learn about the JavaScript Scope.

All that `CreateDelegate` code does it, but is **old** IE8 Microsoft specific Code because Microsoft refused to follow the JavaScript standard

#### Standard JavaScript .bind()

IE9 ( SIX years ago!! ) finally supported the W3C standard JavaScript `bind` method

**Learn:** http://dailyjs.com/post/this-binding

### Get ListID from the GUID

The `get_id()` method returns a SP.Guid **Object**, not a string,

[image]

**do not work with those encoded $ $ keynames!!**

Use the `.toString()` method on the object to get the String value

### So modern code looks like:

```
function getListId(listName) {
    try {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        context.load(list);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
          successFunc.bind({
                          listname:listName,
                          listJSOM:list
                       })
         ,errorFunc);
    } catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
}
function successFunc() {
    console.info(this);
    var thislist = this.listJSOM;// because function call declaration was .bind()
    var listId = thislist.get_id().toString();
    console.log(    this.listname    , 'listid is:' , listId);
}
function errorFunc(sender, args) {
    console.error('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
getListId('Issues');
```

#### Notes:

- **No** Global Variables, so with this pattern you are ready to proces multiple Lists **async**,

  > **each list gets its own instance of the success Function with the proper scope**
- `alert` for debugging is only useful if you really want to waste hours a week clicking on Alert boxes
- I expanded the bind syntax to demonstrate it is easy to pass any data structure you need

**Bind() passes any scope you want** Alas most JavaScript developers copy/paste (CreateDelegate) code and have no clue what they are doing

iBind iJS

Comment: I did copy/paste with an effort to learn what is going on but I guess I need to figure out what is modern code and what is legacy code.

Comment: This results in error "Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'"

Comment: There was another error.. I had deleted the ``context.load(list)`` line. That does not explain your error., which at first sight means the succesFunc is not available .. which.. if you copy this exact code can not be true because the function is hoisted. Use Chrome F12 Code Snippets to code live against a SharePoint page: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery this might work for you

Get all lists:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var lists = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists";

getData();

function getData()
{
    var url = lists;
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) 
        {

            for(i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)
            {
                console.log(data.d.results[i].Id);          
            }                   
        }   
    });
}
});
```

for one list change the url to

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists?$filter=Title eq 'list name'"
```

Comment: This uses the SP2013 REST API, and the OP specifically said SP2010.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think the other answers are over complicating things. If all you want to do is pass a variable (in this case, the listId) to another function, define your function and call it from the success function. See below for a working example (tested in SP13):

```
var list;

function getListId() {
   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Gifts and Hospitality');
   context.load(list, 'Id');

   context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, success), Function.createDelegate(this, error));

}

function success() {
   listId = list.get_id();
   myFunction(listId);
}

function error(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function myFunction (listId) {
   console.log(listId);
}
getListId();
```