# How to copy item to new item then edit new item (cloning a record)

Tags: list, list-item, copy-item

I have records in my database and when viewing a record, I wanted to be able to have a button that would create a new record (new ID number) with the same data that was in the record I chose to create a new one off of. So a user wouldn't have to re-type all of the data in if they would like to change one thing.

So essentially I want to be able to clone a item into a new record.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a little bit of custom code.

The ideal solution will be either to place a custom action in the `Item Context Menu` or in the `Ribbon`. Then clicking that will do the copy of the current selected item and opens up the edit form of the newly created item.

http://sharepointx-men.com/2013/03/13/part-ii-create-new-list-item-by-copy-existing-list-item-and-then-edit-the-newly-created-list-item/

If you don't want this method, then you can use JSOM to get the currently selected item. Then from client side you can create a new item and open up the edit form using `SP.UI.Dialog` or simply redirecting user to that page.

Comment: How do I use jsom for the second method Iv never tried it

Comment: Add a script editor webpart to the page. Then use [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/how-do-you-get-the-current-list-item-in-javascript) to find out the current selected item. Then use [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e18a8/create-an-item-in-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom-javas/) to create a new item

Comment: <CommandUIHandler CommandAction="javascript:viewDialog({ItemId});"/>


function viewDialog(id) {
  var options = {
    url: "/sitename/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx?ID=" + id,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  };

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

Comment: that goes in the script editor snippet?

Comment: Yes. Please read the answer and copy only relevant portion.

Comment: ok so I put this in script editor <CommandUIHandler CommandAction="javascript:viewDialog({ItemId});"/>                Now were does this go function viewDialog(id) {
  var options = {
    url: "/sitename/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx?ID=" + id,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  };

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

Comment: Any thoughts AMAL?